# Ordering associated collection with fetch join in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, hql, left-join

I have a Category table. Every Category can have subcategories. I want to get all Categories from database and also eagerly initialize subcategory collecions. I want them all to be sorted by name property.

Using Comparator works well, and all subcategories are sorted id good order.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentCategory")
@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = InboxCategoryComparator.class)
private SortedSet<InboxCategory> childCategories;

[....]

Criteria criteria = openSession()
    .createCriteria(InboxCategory.class);

criteria
    .setFetchMode( "childCategories", FetchMode.JOIN )
    .setResultTransformer( Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY );
```

But why using ORDER BY clause doesn't work and subcategories are a in random order?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentCategory")
private Set<InboxCategory> childCategories;

[....]

Query q = openSession().createQuery(
    "from InboxCategory category " +
    "left join fetch category.childCategories child " +
    "order by category.name desc, child.name desc");

q.setResultTransformer( new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer() );
```

Comment: Because a Set doesn't maintain any order in its elements.

Comment: In that case, is there any possibility to sort related collection using ORDER BY clause? Something like combining SortedSet and ORDER BY clause? I tried to do that, but removing @Sort annotation generates exception...

Comment: I'd start by using a collection which maintains the order of its elements: a List.

Comment: Thanks! Replacing the Set with a List was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JB Nizet comment, the solution turned out to be so simple. I should have been using a List instead of a Set.